# disabling websocket in Firefox or in my proxy

Tags: firefox, websocket, proxy

I have configured Firefox to use a proxy of mine for http and https. Yes, I write the code for the proxy myself so I'm in complete control there.

As you may know it's no longer possible to disable WebSocket in Firefox through about:config. I'm looking for a lightweight way of disabling it. If it's not possible at all in Firefox I've got to do something in my proxy.

Here's my question: When Firefox is configured to use an http proxy, does it ALWAYS send an http CONNECT request to the proxy to establish the WebSocket connection? What happens if my proxy returns HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed? Is that enough to convince Firefox to abandon WebSocket? Is there any chance that Firefox might bypass my proxy in WebSocket matters after such a response? After all, I haven't configured it to use my proxy for the ws or wss protocols. And ws/wss is NOT disabled in Firefox.

Does Firefox ever send the ws handshake to the proxy, i.e. no CONNECT?

This is about security. I need to make sure that no WebSocket communication slips through. At the same time I want to avoid overkill: No disabling of javascript, no disallowing certain web sites.

Answer (score 22):

This might not answer your direct question, but I think it satisfies your goal.

You can still disable WebSockets by entering the URL `about:config` and then searching for

> network.websocket.max-connections

which you can set the value to 0 to prevent new WebSockets from being created.

Comment: Just tried this in FireFox 64 on Windows and it does not seem to work, with `max-connections` set to zero I am still able to connect via a WebSocket

Comment: This now works as per: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1091016#c24

Comment: @mbrownnyc This is currently not working. Tested with Firefox 89.0 (64-bit) Ubuntu package on Facebook Messenger, I can see the WebSocket messages in Firefox Developer Tools.

Comment: @baptx Perhaps it is a difference between operating systems- using https://www.websocket.org/echo.html on FF 90 on Windows, the websocket does not connect. Likewise on Mac (FF 89). I don't have a Linux device handy to test with.