# How to disable websockets support in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, websocket, firefox-developer-tools

I set `network.websocket.enabled` to `false` in `about:config`.

But when I access the following URL

https://www.aging-us.com/article/102435

a websocket request like the following is still used as shown in the developer tools.

wss://www.aging-us.com/sockjs/829/febrfdll/websocket

What is the correct way to disable websocket in Firefox? Thanks.

Comment: Can you try `network.websocket.max-connextions` per https://stackoverflow.com/q/45963495

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [no preference `network.websocket.enabled` in the code](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/search?q=network.websocket.enabled&path=&case=false&regexp=false), as far as I can see. And there doesn't seem to be any way to completely disable WebSockets, unfortunately.

There was an [enhancement request for allowing to temporarily disable certain features via the DevTools](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1006519), though it got closed due to technical limitations in the engine to do that.

A workaround for that might be to set the preference `network.websocket.max-connections` in `about:config` to `0`. That doesn't disable the feature completely, though at least suppresses any WebSocket connections.